# How to overwrite data in an existing text file using fortran77?

Tags: fortran, fortran77

I'm a beginner at fortran. I already have a code in fortran77 which accepts a text file as an input and processes it to give some output. Now, I need to modify the code so as to create a new text file with would be almost the same as the original input file barring a certain value at a given position in the file, which shall be altered. An example text file would be:-

```
abc  123 mno  456 
value1 =
  0.5265,0.8974,0.,0. /
value2 =
  0.5425,0.8974,0.,0. /
```

I want to overwrite the existing text on the .txt file altering the value1 section to

```
value1 = 
  0.2564,0.8974,0.,0. /
```

How can I do this?

Comment: you really need to show what you have tried so folks know where you are stuck. Do you know how to open a file?

Comment: "you are a beginner at fortran". You are likely not using fortran77, nor should you be in any case.